# Bootstrap modal window won't open because of interference with other elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I can't seem to figure out why bootstrap's modal window isn't popping up.
I've looking into other similar questions and I still can't get it to work.

I've tried the process of elimination and try to eliminate all my scripts (except the bootstrap script) and it still won't open. Same with my CSS files. I also had inputted manual code for a modal window (before I incorporated bootstrap) so I was worried that the id="modal" from other modals would interfere. I deleted those too and nothing worked.

Here is my codepen, I've commented the sections the modal window code starts: https://codepen.io/eylenkim/pen/KKwMPLm

HTML:

```
<!--
   -- fix other <a> tags // fix navigation
   --fix "exit" for contact pop up (mobile)
   -- center the Contact dialog box on viewport in mobile
   -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8"/>
      <title>Art By Eylen | Shop</title>
      <meta name="description" content="Browse Eylen's art portfolio to view work created with 35mm photography, blockprinting, and acrylic.">
      <meta name="author" content="Eylen Kim">
      <!--  data-src
         ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––- -->
      <link href="subpage-stylesheet.css" rel=stylesheet type="text/css">
      <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel=stylesheet type="text/css">
      <link href="skeleton.css" rel=stylesheet type="text/css">
      <link href="otherCss/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <link href="otherCss/font-awesome.css" rel=stylesheet type="text/css">
      <link href="bootstrap-4.3.1-dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel=stylesheet type="text/css">
      <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <!-- Mobile Meta 
         ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––-->
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
      <!--  Favicon
         ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––-->
      <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="photo/favicon1.png" />
   </head>
   <!--   Menu // Hamburger Bar  
      ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––-->
   <nav class="navigation">
      <a href="#" class="menu-icon">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      </a>
      <ul class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
         <div id="nav-x" class="menu-icon">&Cross;</div>
         <li>
            <div href="index.html">
            Home</a>
         </li>
         <li>
            <div href="portfolio.html">
            Portfolio</a>
         </li>
         <li>
            <div class="trigger" style="height: 100%;padding: 10px 0 10px 10px;">
               About Me 
               <div class="modal">
                  <div class="modal-content" style="height: 95%; max-height: 600px;padding: 2rem 4.6rem;">
                     <span class="close-button">&times;</span>
                     <h3>
                        Hello,<br>I'm Eylen!
                     </h3>
                     <img id="about-me-pic" src="photo/meee.JPG">
                     <p style="font-size: .75em; height: 44.3%; padding-top: 15px;">This art website is my passion project. I have coded my own platform to showcase & sell my art. What a treat to have you here on this site!<br><br> The mediums I work with: 35mm film photography, acrylic (canvas & glass), polymer clay (earrings), and printmaking.
                        <br><br>
                        In my free time I like petting my cat, tickling some gnarly tunes on the bass/electric guitar, coding, playing video games, and doing art stuff.<br><br>
                     </p>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </li>
         <li style="height: 100%;padding: 20px 0 10px 7px;">
            <p class="about-me-desktop" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" style="position: relative;top: -3px;">Contact
            </p>
            <div class="w3-container">
               <div id="id01" class="w3-modal">
                  <div class="modal-content-contact-portfolio">
                     <span class="close-button" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" >&times;</span>
                     <h3 style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
                        Contact Me
                     </h3>
                     <p>
                     <div class="contact-us-form" style="font-size: .7em;">
                        <form action="https://formspree.io/eylenkim@gmail.com" method="POST">
                           <div class="row" style="z-index: 9999999;">
                              <div class="six columns">
                                 <input class="u-full-width" type="text" placeholder="Name" id="nameInput" name="Name" requiprintmaking>
                              </div>
                              <div class="six columns">
                                 <input class="u-full-width" type="email" placeholder="Email" id="emailInput" name="Email" requiprintmaking>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                           <textarea class="u-full-width" placeholder="Message" id="messageInput" name="Message" requiprintmaking style="height: 160px;margin-top: 20px;line-height: 17px;padding-top: 8px;"></textarea>
                           <input class="button u-pull-right" type="submit" value="Send" style="color: black;"><br><br><br>
                        </form>
                     </div>
                     </p>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </nav>
   <header>
      <div class="container fade-in">
         <div class="row">
            <a href="index.html">
               <h1 class="one-third column u-pull-left">Art By <span><br></span><span id="h1-title-span"> Eylen</span></h1>
            </a>
            <h2 class="one-third column u-pull-left" id="portfolio-title-desktop">|  Shop</h2>
            <h2 class="one-third column u-pull-left" id="portfolio-title-mobile">
               <span>&boxh;&boxh;<br></span>Shop
            </h2>
            <div class="about-contact-text" class="one-third column u-pull-right">
               <a href="index.html">
                  <p class="about-me-desktop">Home</p>
               </a>
               <span class="trigger">
                  <p class="about-me-desktop">
                     About Me
                  </p>
                  <div class="modal">
                     <div class="modal-content">
                        <span class="close-button">&times;</span>
                        <h3>
                           Hello,<br>I'm Eylen!
                        </h3>
                        <img id="about-me-pic" src="photo/meee.JPG">
                        <p>This art website is my passion project. I have coded my own platform to showcase & sell my art. What a treat to have you here on this site!<br><br> The mediums I work with: 35mm film photography, acrylic (canvas & glass), polymer clay (earrings), and printmaking.
                           <br><br>
                           In my free time I like petting my cat, tickling some gnarly tunes on the bass/electric guitar, coding, playing video games, and doing art stuff.<br><br>
                        </p>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </span>
               <p class="about-me-desktop" onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='block'">
                  Contact
               </p>
               <div class="w3-container">
                  <div id="id02" class="w3-modal">
                     <div class="modal-content-contact">
                        <span class="close-button" onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='none'" >&times;</span>
                        <h3 style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
                           Contact Me
                        </h3>
                        <p>
                        <div class="contact-us-form">
                           <form action="https://formspree.io/eylenkim@gmail.com" method="POST">
                              <div class="overlap-text">
                                 <div class="overlap-text-base-contact">
                                    <h2 class="load two-thirds column">Contact</h2>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="row" style="z-index: 9999999;">
                                 <div class="six columns">
                                    <input class="u-full-width" type="text" placeholder="Name" id="nameInput" name="Name" required>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="six columns">
                                    <input class="u-full-width" type="email" placeholder="Email" id="emailInput" name="Email" required>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                              <br>
                              <textarea class="u-full-width" placeholder="Message" id="messageInput" name="Message" required style="  height: 100px;
                                 margin-top: 10px;
                                 line-height: 17px;
                                 padding-top: 8px;"></textarea>
                              <br><br>
                              <input class="button u-pull-right" type="submit" value="Send"><br><br><br>
                           </form>
                        </div>
                        </p>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
   </header>
   <body class="top" id="top">
   <section class="grid-wrapper">
   <div class="filter-controls">
   <div class="control fade-in">Filter By:
   <select class="filter-field form-control">
   <option value="">None</option>
   <option value="prints">Prints</option>
   <option value="earrings">Earrings</option>
   <option value="commissions">Commisions</option>
   </select>
   </div>
   </div>

   <div class="grid bootstrap-on fade-in" style="flex-direction: row !important;">  

  <!------ Product w/ Carousel ---------------------------------------------------------------------->
   <div class="card item" data-color="earrings"> 
    <div class="price-tag">$10</div>
    <div id="earrings1" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false">
   <div class="carousel-inner">
   <div class="carousel-item active">
   <img src="image" class="d-block w-100 crop-shp" alt="...">
   </div>
   <div class="carousel-item">
   <img src="image" class="d-block w-100 crop-shop" alt="...">
   </div>
   </div>
   <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#earrings1" role="button" data-slide="prev">
   <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
   </a>
   <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#earrings1" role="button" data-slide="next">
   <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
   </a>
     </div>
   <div class="card-body">
   <h5 class="card-title">Carousel</h5>
   <p class="card-text">I want to potentially add the ability to click on the carousel images for the pop up modal</p>
   </div>
   </div>

  <!------ Product w/ Modal Window ---------------------------------------------------------------------->
   <div class="card item" data-color="prints"> 
   <div class="price-tag" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">$10</div>
   <img src="image" class="card-img-top crop-shop" alt="Print" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
   <div class="card-body">
   <h5 class="card-title">(Modal Window)</h5>
   <p class="card-text">I want the modal window to pop up when clickin on the image</p>
   </div>

   </div>
   </div>

   <!-- Modal ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>
   <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
   <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
   <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Cute Earrings</h5>
   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
   <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
   </button>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
   <p>THIS IS THE MODAL!</p>
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Buy</a>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div> 
   </select>       
   </section>
   <!----- Muuri Filtering ----->
   <script>
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      var grid = null,
          wrapper = document.querySelector('.grid-wrapper'),
          searchField = wrapper.querySelector('.search-field'),
          filterField = wrapper.querySelector('.filter-field'),
          sortField = wrapper.querySelector('.sort-field'),
          gridElem = wrapper.querySelector('.grid'),
          searchAttr = 'data-title',
          filterAttr = 'data-color',
          searchFieldValue,
          filterFieldValue,
          sortFieldValue,
          dragOrder = [];

      // Init the grid layout
      grid = new Muuri(gridElem, {
        dragEnabled: false,
        layout: {
          fillGaps: true
        }
      });

      // Filter field event binding
      filterField.addEventListener('change', filter);

      // Sort field event binding
      sortField.addEventListener('change', sort);

      // Filtering
      function filter() {
        filterFieldValue = filterField.value;
        grid.filter(function (item) {
          var element = item.getElement(),
              isSearchMatch = !searchFieldValue ? true : (element.getAttribute(searchAttr) || '').toLowerCase().indexOf(searchFieldValue) > -1,
              isFilterMatch = !filterFieldValue ? true : (element.getAttribute(filterAttr) || '') === filterFieldValue;
          return isSearchMatch && isFilterMatch;
        });
      }
      });

   </script>
   <script src="js/muuri.js"></script>
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/web-animations-js@2.3.2/web-animations.min.js"></script>
   <!--Modal - Dialog Boxes -->
   <script type="text/javascript"> const modals = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.modal'));
      const triggers = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.trigger'));
      var closeButton = document.querySelector(".close-button"); 

      //if a trigger is clicked then...
      for (const trigger of triggers) {
        trigger.addEventListener('click', toggleModal);
      }

      // .. then toggle it's modal
      function toggleModal(event) { event.target.closest('.trigger').querySelector('.modal').classList.toggle("show-modal"); }

        // check if the clicked element is a modal, or in a modal
      function windowOnClick(event) {
        if (modals.some((modal) => modal.contains(event.target))) {
          toggleModal();
        }
      }
   </script>
   <script>
      function closeButton() {
        document.getElementByClass('id02').style.display='none'
      }

   </script>
   <!----- JS files ----->
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script> 
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/singlenav.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scrollreveal.js"></script> 
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vanilla-lazyload@12.4.0/dist/lazyload.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <a href="#top" id="return-to-top"><i class="icon-chevron-up"></i></a>  
   <!----- Lazy Load ----->
   <script>
      (function() {
        function logElementEvent(eventName, element) {
          console.log(
            Date.now(),
            eventName,
            element.getAttribute("data-src")
          );
        }
        var callback_enter = function(element) {
          logElementEvent(" ENTERED", element);
        };
        var callback_exit = function(element) {
          logElementEvent(" EXITED", element);
        };
        var callback_reveal = function(element) {
          logElementEvent("️ REVEALED", element);
        };
        var callback_loaded = function(element) {
          logElementEvent(" LOADED", element);
        };
        var callback_error = function(element) {
          logElementEvent(" ERROR", element);
          element.src =
            "https://via.placeholder.com/440x560/?text=Error+Placeholder";
        };
        var callback_finish = function() {
          logElementEvent("✔️ FINISHED", document.documentElement);
        };
        ll = new LazyLoad({
          elements_selector: ".lazy",
          load_delay: 300,
          threshold: 0,
          // Assign the callbacks defined above
          callback_enter: callback_enter,
          callback_exit: callback_exit,
          callback_reveal: callback_reveal,
          callback_loaded: callback_loaded,
          callback_error: callback_error,
          callback_finish: callback_finish
        });


      })();
   </script>
   <!----- Scroll To Top ----->
   <script>
      $(window).scroll(function() {
          if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 600) {        // If page is scrolled more than 50px
              $('#return-to-top').fadeIn(200);    // Fade in the arrow
          } else {
              $('#return-to-top').fadeOut(200);   // Else fade out the arrow
          }
      });
      $('#return-to-top').click(function() {      // When arrow is clicked
          $('body,html').animate({
              scrollTop : 0                       // Scroll to top of body
          }, 500);
      });
   </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 separate issues that are preventing the modal from showing up.

### 1) The first issue is with your code

#### The bootstrap library you use returns 404.

- How to check if it's happening for you?

  - Open your browser's inspector, and press CTRL+SHIFT+I
  - You will see:

    - `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()   eylenkim/fullpage/bootstrap-4.3.1-dist/css/bootstrap.css`
  - In fact, this happens for a lot of your relative URLs.

#### Solution

Replace links to Bootstrap libraries with working ones, eg. from https://getbootstrap.com/

The ones I used in my testing of your code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

See gist for minimum code sample for a modal here: https://codepen.io/edwin-chua/pen/rNaLOEg

Once you fix the link problem, you will run into the second issue.

### 2) The second issue is with your stylesheet

Once you fixed your code as I suggested, you get a dark overlay with no modal.

Removing the reference to `https://eylenkim.github.io/ArtByEylen/StyleSheet.css` allows the modal to show up, so something in here is interfering with the modal's css.

Here is a working pen: https://codepen.io/edwin-chua/pen/QWwEyyZ

### Separate Problem

You seem to have imported some libraries twice, once in the Codepen UI, and once in the HTML file. This will cause you debugging headaches. Make sure you only import them once. Since you are building an entire webpage, I suggest putting all of it in the HTML file.

[image: Screenshot 1]

*also see JS tab*

And

[image]

#### Further Comments

This section of code seems to be for closing the modal? If so, it probably isn't required, as Bootstrap automatically binds the click events.

```html
<!--Modal - Dialog Boxes -->
   <script type="text/javascript"> const modals = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.modal'));
      const triggers = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.trigger'));
      var closeButton = document.querySelector(".close-button"); 

      //if a trigger is clicked then...
      for (const trigger of triggers) {
        trigger.addEventListener('click', toggleModal);
      }

      // .. then toggle it's modal
      function toggleModal(event) { event.target.closest('.trigger').querySelector('.modal').classList.toggle("show-modal"); }

        // check if the clicked element is a modal, or in a modal
      function windowOnClick(event) {
        if (modals.some((modal) => modal.contains(event.target))) {
          toggleModal();
        }
      }
   </script>
```